# Angular 5 pass headers properly in http get requests

Tags: angular, angular5

so initially i was using the deprecated HttpModule for my api requests but i'm using the HttpClientModule now and having issues with passing headers correctly. i've got a function that calls api to get some data...this is what i had initially with HttpModule

> service.ts

```
export class userService {
  //using HttpModule
  getCurrentProfile() {
    let v = this.page_header();
    return this.http.get(this.userProfileUrl, {headers: headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  };

  //using HttpClientModule
  getCurrentProfile() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    return this.http.get(this.userProfileUrl, {headers: headers})
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  };

  private page_header() {
    let data = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    let headers = new Headers();
    let opt: RequestOptions;
    headers.append('Authorization', 'JWT ' + data);
    opt = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return opt;
  }
}
```

> component.ts

```
getStoreProfile() {
 //using HttpModule
 this.userSrv.getCurrentProfile().then(response => {
   localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(response));
   this.profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store'));
 }).catch(err => this.error = err)

 //using HttpClientModule
 this.userSrv.getCurrentProfile().subscribe(res => {
  let data = res;
  localStorage.setItem('store', JSON.stringify(res));
  this.profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store'));
})
```

}
So initailly it all worked with HttpModule but now with HttpClientModule i get errro

```
detail:"Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

How am i to pass headers correctly using HttpClientModule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> detail:"Authentication credentials were not provided."

You are getting this issue because your header is empty.

use  `httpOptions` object to send header
 In new `HttpClientModule` JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed using `res.json()`
 it's recommended to use `observables` over `promises`. By converting to a promise you will lose the ability to cancel a request and the ability to chain RxJS operators.

```
 getCurrentProfile():Observable<any> {
    let data = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
      const httpOptions = {
                headers: new HttpHeaders({
                    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
                        'Authorization': ' 'JWT ' + data'
         })
    };

        return this.http.get(this.userProfileUrl, httpOptions)
         .catch(this.handleError);
      };
```

Comment: using your code i encountered some error on ide so i tried fixing but one more red line
property 'json' does not exist on type 'object'
here is what i have
        getCurrentProfile() {
 let data = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
 const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Authorization': ' ',JWT: ' + data'
  })
 };
 return this.http.get(this.userProfileUrl, httpOptions)
  .toPromise()
  .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(this.handleError);
 };
red line just after .toPromise()...sorry code not format properly

Comment: Oh la la...thanks man, working now. issue was really in the header, had to console.log and see then concatenate properly...now it is working. Thanks really.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: It helped me to set the headers for api call. But, i have one question in my api call header. i'll be having more than one header property like Access-Token, User-ID and User-IP how to set these property accordingly?  @Vikas

Answer (score 1):

Better you adopt a new way of handling the Headers: Use the Interceptor

```
import { AuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```